# How can I get a list of substrings from a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, parsing, substring, sql-like

I have a table of products, and each product has a Description field. Some of these Descriptions contain a pdf name, such as "productmanual.pdf". I need to find out all of the pdf names that exist in my product descriptions. I was able to get all of the Descriptions that contain a pdf as such:

```
SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Description] LIKE '%.pdf%'
```

but the descriptions are very long and I have a over a thousand products returned. I need to parse out just the PDF titles and return a list of those. I know that each title begins after a "<" and ends with ".pdf", in C# I would parse them like this:

```
var pdfIndex = description.IndexOf(".pdf");
if ((pdfIndex) > -1){
    var pdfEnd = pdfIndex + 3;
    var stringBefore = description.Substring(0, pdfIndex);
    var pdfStart = stringBefore.LastIndexOf(">");
    var pdfLength = pdfEnd - pdfStart;
    var pdfString = description.Substring(pdfStart + 1, pdfLength);
}
```

How can I accomplish this in SQL so that I can return a list all the (distinct) PDF titles?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s..i assume it should be sql server based on `[]` around table and column names

Comment: If it is sql server, perhaps a recursive cte would work

Comment: Are there multiple PDFs in one description? Or is it only ever one PDF per description?

Answer (score 1):

This would work assuming all the descriptions have only one `.` followed by `pdf`.

```
SELECT substring([Description], 
                 charindex('<', [Description]) + 1,
                 charindex('.', [Description]) - charindex('<', [Description]) - 1) as filename
FROM [Product] 
WHERE [Description] LIKE '%.pdf%'
and charindex('.', [Description]) > 0 and charindex('>', [Description]) > 0
```

Edit:

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e739c/3)

```
SELECT reverse(substring(reverse([Description]), 
                charindex('.', reverse([Description])) + 1,
                charindex('>', reverse([Description])) 
                              - charindex('.', reverse([Description])) - 1) 
               ) as filename
FROM [Product] 
WHERE [Description] LIKE '%.pdf%'
and charindex('.', [Description]) > 0 and charindex('>', [Description]) > 0
```

Comment: That's awesome, the only issue is that the descriptions can have multiple '>' characters. I need to find the last '>' before the PDF. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: where is `>` coming from? you said the filename starts with `<` and ends in `.pdf`?

Comment: No, the description looks something like "For additional information or to request a quote, please email customerservice@msdistributors.com<br/><br/><strong>Manufacturer:</strong> Respironics<br/><strong>Image Disclaimer:</strong> Do not order based on the image alone. The image displayed may not represent the specific product you are ordering.<br/><strong>MSDS:</strong> remstar pro manual.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a recursive CTE will work for you.

```
DECLARE @f VARCHAR(255)
SET @f = '>1.pdf test >2.pdf bob >3.pdf foo >4.pdf'

; WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), SUBSTRING(
            @f, 
            PATINDEX('%>%.pdf%', @f) + 1,
            (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', @f) + 4) - (PATINDEX('%>%.pdf%', @f) + 1)
        )) AS PDFName,

        CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), STUFF(
            @f, PATINDEX('%>%.pdf%', @f), 
            (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', @f) + 4) - (PATINDEX('%>%.pdf%', @f)),
            ''
        )) AS strWhatsLeft

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), SUBSTRING(
            strWhatsLeft, 
            PATINDEX('%>%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 1,
            (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 4) - (PATINDEX('%>%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 1)
        )) AS PDFName,

        CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), STUFF(
            strWhatsLeft, PATINDEX('%>%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft), 
            (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 4) - (PATINDEX('%>%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft)),
            ''
        )) AS strWhatsLeft
    FROM cte
    WHERE strWhatsLeft LIKE '%.pdf%'
)

SELECT * FROM cte
```

With the given test string, it will return

```
PDFName strWhatsLeft
1.pdf    test >2.pdf bob >3.pdf foo >4.pdf
2.pdf    test  bob >3.pdf foo >4.pdf
3.pdf    test  bob  foo >4.pdf
4.pdf    test  bob  foo
```

Comment: So I just realized you may have multiple '>' characters before the pdf file name. In which case, you will need more complicated substringing to get what you need. But the basic building blocks are in my code.